# Unable to run the Speech module in python 3.6 in windows 7?

Tags: python-3.x, speech

I am using python 3.6 and I have faced an error in importing the speech module in Windows 7.

```
import speech
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import pyttsx3


counter = 0

while True:
    print ("Talk:")
    phrase = speech.input()
    print("HERE")
    print (phrase)

    if phrase == "Friday":
        speech.say("Yes sir!, at your service!")
    if phrase == ("What's the day today"):
        os.system(r"D:\python_github_testing\Basic_Ai-master\checkDay.vbs")
```

I got the following error

> Talk: Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "D:\python_github_testing\Basic_Ai-master\testingFriday.py", line 12,
>   in 
>       phrase = speech.input()    File "C:\Users\nnkashyap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\speech.py",
>   line 165, in input
>       listener = listenforanything(response)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\nnkashyap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\speech.py",
>   line 196, in listenforanything
>       return _startlistening(None, callback)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\nnkashyap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\speech.py",
>   line 245, in _startlistening
>       grammar.DictationSetState(1)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\NNKASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.6\C866CA3A-32F7-11D2-9602-00C04F8EE628x0x5x4.py",
>   line 2485, in DictationSetState
>       return self.*oleobj*.InvokeTypes(16, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((3, 1),),State pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.',
>   (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147023728), None)

How should I resolve it?

Comment: Could you please re-format your code, and add more information on your system, libraries version, what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to do a Speech to Text recognition using speech module of python. I am using windows 7. But the module is of version python 2.7 and I am using python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's your problem! You can't mix different versions of Python and libraries, as they're usually built for compliance with specific versions.

[`speech`](https://pypi.org/project/speech/) is a 10-year-old module, and as far as I can see, there's no support for newer python versions (and the `pywintypes` error might hint on that).

There are [several](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/), [new](https://pypi.org/project/talkey/) [packages](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/), [projects](https://pypi.org/project/py-espeak-ng/), and [APIs](https://pythonspot.com/speech-recognition-using-google-speech-api/), which you can use to get started with Speech recognition and/or Text-to-Speech. They almost all decently documented, with tutorials and Get-Started guides, so you'd be better off choosing one of them. The alternative is to return working with Python 2.7, which I would not suggest, as it's 2019.

As a bonus, look into creating a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for your Python3.6, so you have an isolated environment with only the correct libraries using `python3 -m venv /path/to/project`, but that's something for the future!